# How Many Org-Wide email Addressese can be Created in Salesforce

Tags: email

Question is very straight forward. Answer would be, as much ORG-wide email addresses we want can be created.

But is there any **official** note which can prove that 2000 Org-Wide emails can be created or only 100 Org-Wide can be created? Any figures?

Comment: Well, we have 1000+ (am I rich) SFDC license So, how much Org-Wides emails I can have  :) Atleast the ratio. @bigassforce